# how to apply strftime on localtime

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to get the day of the month from a datetime column in my Sqlite database. I could use simply

```
select strftime('%d',myColumn) from myTable
```

But the values are stored in UTC in the database and i want to get the dates based on the localtime. So i can do the below to get the localtime.

```
select date(myColumn, 'localtime') from myTable
```

Now how do i do both these operations together? The only way i can think is by doing inner query with the `date()` and outer query with `strftime()`. Is there another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says that modifiers like `localtime` are used with all date and time functions:

```
SELECT strftime('%d', myColumn, 'localtime') FROM myTable
```